# Ajax or async call to upload file

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, uploadify

OK, this is really a tricky question I really have no idea to do it. I need to add uploading file feature to a asp.net web application.
First I used uploadify (a jquery add-on), it could upload file to server with ajax, but it require Flash. Business are not happy with that.
Second, I used valums ajax upload, it is the same with uploadify, but it does not require Flash. Then business are still not happy, they prefer "html upload", means they don't want use any third party library or jquery add-on.

OK. the question is, I have a big Form, i need to put upload button inside the form, but I don't want to submit the form to upload file, I just want to uplaod file asyncronisely, is there any way to do that. no add-on, no third-party library, no need to submit the whole form, because I know I can't embeded a upload form inside another form.

I am really strugglling, any help apprecite it.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can use the file API, but I added that info to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [form](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/file.html).

If you can't do that, try the file API. It's only available on modern browsers, so that might not be an option. The file API is the only way that I know of to upload a file asynchronously (without posting a form).

Here is the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/), the [Mozilla API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_files_from_web_applications), and  a [demo](http://html5demos.com/file-api).  The file API can be used without the drag and drop (it just uses `<input type='file'>` I believe.  If the user does not do a drag-and-drop, then they have to OK each file you try to use from the local machine. Annoying, yes, but it's safer.

Comment: I said I could not use a form inside another form.

Answer (score 0):

"AJAX", cannot be used for file uploads. To get the asynchronous behaviour iframes must be used.

Create a form just for uploading the file(s). Iframe this upload form inside your main form.

You will need to sync the two forms, it would be easy to provide the object ID in post parameters when the files are uploaded.

Comment: It can be if you use the file API in HTML5.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that you need to employ one of the many "hidden iframe" javascript solutions that you will find with a quick google search.